# How did NOKIA N9 pppd to network?

Tags: linux, ppp

When use wcdma module ,we should use ppp protocol to communicate with ppp server. But I can't see any file about ppp in NOKIA N9's filesystem.

So,How N9 use linux(harmattan) to dial to PPP server and then linked to internet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This question seems more suited to [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com) - it is not related to programming. See the [StackOverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information on what kind of questions you can ask here.
2. Regardless of where you post a question, it would help all of us if you provided more context, preferably using full sentences. As it stands now, it is difficult to tell what your actual question is. Do you want to connect a computer to the internet using the phone? Do you want to use the phone itself to access the network?

   It is also difficult to understand what the problem is. You should at least tell us what you have tried and where that failed.

   Unless you pay more attention to your question, you will not get any meaningful answers. You should probably have a look [here](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) for a guide on asking questions.
3. You should keep in mind that hardware-related questions can usually be answered only by people that have access to that particular device. With the amount of information you are providing this question boils down to "How do I connect to a PPP server on Nokia N9?", which is impossible to answer, unless one has access to that particular phone model.

   By providing more context, such as describing *how* the firmware in that phone is setup, you allow people that have more general experience on Linux and embedded devices to help you.

Since I do not have that particular device, I will take a shot in the dark and offer a few alternatives, in order of decreasing probability:

1. You may need to install additional packages. I believe that [MeeGo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_N9#Software) uses Debian-style packages and the PPP-related packages may not be installed by default. You should have a look at your software repositories.
2. The PPP support does not have to be a module - it can be included in the main kernel binary. `pppd` could also be replaced by a custom binary, although that is not very common, even on embedded devices.
3. Are you *absolutely certain* that your current software configuration does not support PPP? How are you searching in the filesystem for PPP-related files? What are you expecting to find? Does using the phone UI to connect work?
4. There is a *very slim* chance that the default firmware does not support PPP at all - in that case you may have to install custom packages or even replace the firmware itself with a custom version.

Comment: Thanks,what I want to know is : the smart Phone like N9 or android phone connect to internet via wcdma module,and whether they use ppp protocol ?